# Does $h_n = T(h_{n-1})$ for a compact operator $T$ imply that $h_n$ is a bounded sequence?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness

Let $h_n$ be a sequence in a Hilbert space $H$, and let $T:H \to H$ be a compact and bounded operator. If
$$h_n = T(h_{n-1})$$
holds, does it follow that $\lVert h_n \rVert \leq C$ uniformly in $n$?

Since $T$ is bounded, the result is true if the operator norm of is less than or equal to one. Without this property, could it still hold by some compactness argument? $T$ may be nonlinear by the way.

Comment: Compactness gives you a convergent subsequence and this subsequence will be bounded but I don't think you know anything more about the whole sequence

Comment: Ignore that actually - to use the compactness of $T:H\to H$ the sequence in the domain has to be bounded. I.e images of bounded sequences contain convergent subsequences. So I don't think compactness helps

Comment: Let $T : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ by $T((x_n)) = 2\langle x,e_1\rangle e_1$, and take $h_0 = e_1$, then $T$ is compact, but $\|h_n\| = 2^{n+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $(a_j) \in c_0$ (the space of sequences converging to $0$) the multiplication operator $K:\ell^2 \to \ell^2$ defined by $K(x)_j = a_j x_j$ is compact and bounded with $\lvert \lvert K \rvert \rvert = \lvert \lvert a \rvert \rvert_\infty$.

Take $a_j = 2^{2-j}$ for $j \geq 1$ so $(a_j) \in c_0$. Let $h_0 = e_1$ where $\{e_j:j \geq 1 \}$ is the standard complete orthonormal sequence in $\ell^2$ and define the sequence $h_k$ as in the question. Then $h_k = 2^k e_1$ so $\lvert \lvert h_k \rvert \rvert_2 = 2^k$.